# VBA - copying filtered rows multiple times

Tags: vba, autofilter

I would like to filter and copy rows of a table based on different criteria (let's say two criteria). The rows should be copied to another sheet in two ranges (in the first range if they satify the first criteria, in the second if they satisfy the second.

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance

Simone

Comment: You can probably achieve that with a `For i = 1 To 2` loop.  Just embed your existing code that does one of the filter / copy steps within the loop, and change all the bits that are different for the second step to use arrays with an index of `i`.  (If you show your existing code to do one filter / copy, we can help explain better how to set up the loop.)

Answer (score 0):

Considering multiple criteria context, i suggest using array will make your  code concise, easier maintenance.

assume you need the output data to be copied to one sheet:

```
Sub loopingFilter()
Dim Arr1, Arr2 As Variant
Dim i, j1, j2, St1_Row
Dim St1, St2

Set St1 = Sheets("Input")
Set St2 = Sheets("Output")
St1_Row = St1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
j1 = 0: j2 = 0

For i = St1_Row To 2 Step -1
'assuming status is your critiria range
Status = St1.Cells(i, 1).Value

If Status = "YourCriteria1" Then
    Arr1(j1) = Range("A" & i & ":Z" & i)
    j1 = j1 + 1 'increment array index     
ElseIf Status = "YourCriteria2" Then
    Arr2(j2) = Range("A" & i & ":Z" & i)
    j2 = j2 + 1 'increment array index       
End If

Next i

'Output array into OUTPUT sheet, if put in one sheet
St2.Range("A1:Z" & j1) = Arr1()
St2.Range("A" & (j1 + 2) & ":Z" & j2) = Arr2()
End Sub
```

A shorter version would be using Ubound, but looks not as clean as previous, hope my answer helps :)

```
Sub loopingFilter1()
ReDim Arr(0) : Dim i, St1_Row : Dim St1, St2
Set St1 = Sheets("Input") : Set St2 = Sheets("Output")
St1_Row = St1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to St1_Row
'assuming status is your critiria range
Status = St1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    If Status = "YourCriteria" Then
        Arr(UBound(Arr)) = Range("A" & i & ":Z" & i)
        ReDim Preserve Arr(UBound(Arr) + 1)    
    End if
Next i

St2.Range("A1:Z" & UBound(Arr)) = Arr()
End Sub
```